# Is there a "set" data structure in bash?

Tags: bash, set

Python has a "set" type which contains unique objects.
Does Bash have something equivalent?

I want to keep adding elements to such a bash "set" and never have duplicates.

Comment: I don't think bash provide such a data structure. In the past, I stored my strings into a file, then sort | uniq

Comment: you can build such a creature as functions (if_in_set(item,arr), add_setItem(item,arr), (del_setItem(item,arr) ), but you're basically doing a for loop on an array, and if you find the key already used, then you reject the add, else you add the new item. Depending on your needs, this is OK. If your need is a one time, and or urgent, then `mySet="$(sort -u tmpFile)"` maybe good enough. Good luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bash 4.0 has associative arrays, which can be used to build sets.

[Here's an article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-associative-arrays) that discusses them (it was the first Google hit for "bash associative arrays").

(Personally, I'd just use something other than bash, probably Perl.)

Comment: Ruby is awesome for scripting; My personal favorite

Comment: How can you build sets with associative arrays?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Use the members of the set as the keys, and some arbitrary value as the corresponding value.

Answer (score 18):

```
some_dups=(aa aa b b c)
uniques=($(for v in "${some_dups[@]}"; do echo "$v";done| sort| uniq| xargs))
echo "${uniques[@]}"
```

gives

```
aa b c
```

also in bash 3, where no associative arrays are available

Comment: Thanks! You can also simplify: `uniques=($(for v in "${some_dups[@]}"; do echo "$v";done| sort -u))`

Answer (score 16):

After some googling I found a nice bash implementation at http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/. It has all the usual set operators in multiple ways, and even a printable pdf cheatsheet.

I've used associative arrays though, it's much more readable.

Declare a `setA` associative array variable:

```
$ declare -A setA
```

Or declare and add the initial members at the same time:

```
$ declare -A setA=([memberA]=1 [memberB]=1)
```

Add a member to the set:

```
$ setA[memberC]=1
```

Test for membership:

```
$ [ -n "${setA[memberC]}" ] && echo in set || echo not in set
in set

$ [ -n "${setA[memberD]}" ] && echo in set || echo not in set
not in set
```

List members (space separated):

```
$ echo "${!setA[@]}"
memberA memberC memberB
```

or (newline separated):

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${!setA[@]}"
memberB
memberC
memberA
```

Iterate through members:

```
$ for m in "${!setA[@]}"; do echo "$m"; done
memberB
memberC
memberA
```

Cardinality (number of members in the set):

```
$ echo ${#setA[@]}
3
```

Remove a member:

```
$ unset setA[memberC]
```

Use quotes to add members with spaces in their name:

```
$ setA["member with space"]=1
```

And it's possible to use variables as members too:

```
$ read -r str
$ setA["$str"]=1
```