# git: How to remove *all* files from the git history that are not currently present?

Tags: git

I've seen several articles and questions about how to remove a *single* file from all git history. Example: [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

What I'd like to do is remove *all* files that are not *currently present* at the head of the master branch.

My use case is that I'm splitting off a smaller repository (call it `small`) from a monolithic repository (call it `monolith`). I want to preserve the git history when creating `small`, but only the *relevant* git history.

First, I created a new repository `small` on GitHub. Then, on my laptop, I added it as a remote named `origin-small` to my local `monolith` repository, and pushed the current state of the master branch of `monolith` to `origin-small`.

I then removed the remote `origin-small` from `monolith`, changed directories, and cloned `small` from GitHub. Voilà, I had a copy of my original repository, `monolith`, with its full history.

But, there are loads of files in the history of `small` that are no longer relevant, and they are bloating the repo.

What I'd like to do is:

1. Delete all of the unnecessary files from `small`.
2. Run a command to clear the whole git history of the files that I just deleted.

Is there a way to do this with a single command? Or do I need to run `git filter-branch` once for every file/directory that I want to remove?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ended up using `git-filter-repo`. **WARNING: This approach is NOT able to update tags on the remote, if there are any.**

1. Install `git-filter-repo`.

   ```
   brew install git-filter-repo
   ```
2. Clone your desired repo, in mirror form.

   ```
   git clone --mirror <my-repo-url>
   ```
3. Enter the repo directory.

   ```
   cd <my-repo-name>
   ```
4. Analyze the repo to identify all files that are in the history, but no longer exist.

   ```
   git filter-repo --analyze
   ```
5. In the `analysis` output directory, there will be a file named `path-deleted-sizes.txt` that contains a list all files that were committed at some point, and were later deleted, but still exist in the git history.

   Create a new file that lacks the headers and other columns.

   ```
   tail +3 ./filter-repo/analysis/path-deleted-sizes.txt \
       | tr -s ' ' \
       | cut -d ' ' -f 5- \
       > ./filter-repo/analysis/path-deleted.txt
   ```
6. Clean the git history of all files that no longer exist. This will also clean dirty commits, remove empty commits, and recompress everything for you.

   ```
   git filter-repo --invert-paths --paths-from-file ./filter-repo/analysis/path-deleted.txt
   ```
7. Clean up the `./filter-repo` directory, or you won't be able to push your changes.

   ```
   rm -rf ./filter-repo
   ```
8. Force-push all refs to the origin. It will force-push, even though the command doesn't indicate it. Also, it will update *all* branches on the remote, which is convenient. If you have branch protection enabled on some branches in GitHub/Bitbucket/etc., then you will need to allow force-pushes. You can always re-run this command if you find that some refs could not be force-pushed.

   ```
   git push
   ```

Comment: See also: [How to identify large files in commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42544963/562769)

Comment: This is great, but `./filter-repo` should be replaced with `.git/filter-repo` to make this work out of the box. It's where `git-filter-repo` places the results by default now.

Comment: Actually if you mirror the repo and you don't have a .git folder and the path described in the post is correct.

Answer (score 4):

List all the files that exist in the old commits.

```
git rev-list HEAD | sed 1d | xargs -i git ls-tree -r {} --name-only | sort -u
```

List all the files that exist in the head.

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | sort -u
```

Get the files that don't exist in the head ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964477/6330106)).

```
files=$(comm -23 <(git rev-list HEAD | sed 1d | xargs -i git ls-tree -r {} --name-only | sort -u) <(git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | sort -u))
```

Replace the invisible characters (which I guess are new-lines) with spaces, otherwise it would cause an error in `git filter-branch`.

```
lostfiles=$(echo $files | sed -e 's/\s/ /g')
```

Remove `lostfiles` from the history:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter "rm -rf ${lostfiles}" --prune-empty
```

It's possible to compose them to a single command, but I don't know if there would be any performance issue, so I'd prefer separate commands.