# Get unique array values using mask

Tags: arrays, linux, macos, bash, sorting

I have an array of URLs and corresponding domains
Delimiter for array values is `\n`
Domain/Url delimiter is comma

```
site1.com,www.site1.com/blahA-blahB-blahC   
site2.com,site2.com/blahD-blahE-blahF   
site2.com,site2.com/blahG-blahH-blahI   
site3.com,site3.com/blahJ-blahK-blahL
```

I would like to filter this array and remove lines that contain domain duplicates (1st occurrence stays). Required output is as follows:

```
site1.com,www.site1.com/blahA-blahB-blahC   
site2.com,site2.com/blahD-blahE-blahF   
site3.com,site3.com/blahJ-blahK-blahL
```

Please, advise.

Comment: This thread might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099887/is-there-a-set-data-structure-in-bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `awk` command,

```
awk -F/ '!x[$1]++' file
```

Output:

```
site1.com,www.site1.com/blahA-blahB-blahC
site2.com,site2.com/blahD-blahE-blahF
site3.com,site3.com/blahJ-blahK-blahL
```